# Allocate memory for a dynamic array of static arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, typedef

I've read plenty of posts about this, but it seems, that my problem is a bit more specific. I think I would manage to allocate a dynamic 2d array.

Due to existing code, I have to use a `typedef` which is a static array. Now I want to store an unknown number of these arrays temporarily. I've tried several variations with pointers, but I can't even compile it.

Following code should explain what I'm trying to do:

```
int                     iCount, i;
typedef unsigned char   Buffer[1024];

Buffer       *          BufferArray=NULL;

BufferArray = malloc(iCount * sizeof Buffer*);

for(i=0;i<iCount;i++)
{
    BufferArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(Buffer));
}
```

This is my version with fewest errors. The only one left is

> error C2106: '=' left operand must be l-value

I know this topic is tedious and occurred often enough. Though, I'm getting quite confused with the `typedef`, which is already a static array. So I thought, a `**` pointer is not needed here.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Side note: You are assigning to `BufferArray[iCount]` instead of `BufferArray[i]` which is most likely not what you intended.

Comment: Side note: The above can't be real code, it won't compile. I don't believe in `iCount * sizeof Buffer*`.

Comment: Right, shoulb be [i]. @unwind: I know, it doesn't compile, as i wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the typedef confuses you, then remove it (in your head):

```
typedef unsigned char   Buffer[1024];
```

So when we see `Buffer`, think of it as a unsigned char array of [1024].

```
Buffer * BufferArray=NULL; // really it's: unsigned char[] *
```

Now you're looking to hold onto an unknown number of these arrays. Well you're not really using a 2D dynamic array, just a single dynamic array that happens to hold static arrays:

```
typedef unsigned char Buffer[1024];

int main(void) {
    Buffer * BA = NULL;
    int iCount = 5;
    BA = malloc(iCount * sizeof(Buffer));
    BA[0][0] = 10;
    return 0; 
}
```

Now `BA` is a dynamically created array you can use to temporarily hold `iCount` number of static unsigned char arrays (`Buffer`).

Answer (score 0):

if you want to copy a elements of dynamic array from dynamic array to static array. There is a below simple solution.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#define r 2
#define c 5

int main()
{
    char *p;
    char a[r][c];
    int i,j;

    p=(char*)malloc(r*c*sizeof(char));
    gets(p);
    puts(p);

    while(*p!='\0')
    {
        for(i=0;i<=r-1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0; j<=c-1; j++)
            {
                a[i][j] =* p;
                ("%c",a[i][j]);
                p++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return (0);
}
```